# How to round average in Java stream?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I want to calculate the average of a list of integers and then round the result to half up (i.e. >= .5 is  rounded to nearest integer up and < .5 is rounded to the nearest integer down). How do I do this with Java stream ?

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(60);
    values.add(30);
    values.add(20);

    double avg = values.stream().mapToInt(a -> a).average().getAsDouble();

    System.out.println(avg);
}
```

I was hoping for something like

```
...average().round(RoundingMode.HALF_UP).getAsInt();
```

Comment: `IntStream.of(60, 30, 20).average().stream().map(Math::round).findFirst().getAsDouble();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intent is to round the result, not values within the stream itself. So just wait until you have the double, then round that value with `Math.round()` by replacing this:

```
System.out.println(avg);
// output: 36.666666666666664
```

with this:

```
System.out.println(Math.round(avg));
// output: 37
```

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing/

Answer (score 1):

This would work Java 9 onward;

```
double avg = values.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                .average()
                .stream()
                .map(Math::round)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

what about [rounding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) that double??

```
avg = Math.round(avg);
System.out.println(avg);
```